# Is it possible to get the instance of the parent object inside a __proto__ function?

Tags: javascript, object

```
// module

const obj = {
  geo: {}
}

const func = function(){}

func.__proto__.setGeo = function({lon, lat} = {}){
  return this.obj.geo = {lon, lat};
}

const parentObject = {
  func,
  obj
}

module.exports = parentObject

// controller

const parentObject = require('./module')

parentObject.func.setGeo({lon: 1, lat: 2})
```

Apparently this doesn't work because `this` inside setGeo is pointing to `func`.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work. Why are you doing weird things here? What do you do with `__proto__`? Why is `func` an empty function, and why is `setGeo` a method of `func` instead of `obj` itself?

Comment: No, a method called on `parentObject.func` will never be able to access the `parentObject` dynamically, without already knowing it. In your case, you could simply refer to the module constant `obj`.

Comment: @Bergi setGeo is really just a sub feature of func. func is empty because people don't need to know what it does to answer the question.

Comment: Still, why are you modifying `func.__proto__`, which is `Function.prototype` - which you should never touch?

Comment: Sure, because the assignment I received is to allow other developers to use `parentObject.func.setGeo` to set geo info while using `parentObject.func` to active the main feature.

Comment: No, don't do that. Just assign `func.setGeo = function() { … };`. Do not use `__proto__`!

Comment: Again that is the assignment/requirement. It must be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `obj` directly into `parentObject` You have to inherit the `obj` into `func`. Then your `setGeo` on proto will access `obj` using this instance. Check the changes below.

```
// module

const obj = {
  geo: {}
}

const func = function(){}

func.__proto__.obj = obj; // Inheriting parent

func.__proto__.setGeo = function({lon, lat} = {}){
  return this.obj.geo = {lon, lat};
}

const parentObject = {
  func
}

module.exports = parentObject

// controller

const parentObject = require('./module')

parentObject.func.setGeo({lon: 1, lat: 2})
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I did eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be reduced to a scenario where you want to get access to the parent object of the function.

```
o = {
    f: function() {console.log(this)},
    g: 1
}
```

Now, the `this` keyword will point to the calling context always. However, the calling context can be varying in different scenarios.

1. A plain function call.

   ```
   o.f();
   ```

   In this case, the calling context is the `o` object - which is what you are trying to access.
2. Calling the function in a specific context

   ```
           o.f.call({name: 'new context'})
   ```

   In this case, the calling context is `{name: 'new context'}`
3. Using the function as a constructor

   ```
           obj = new o.f()
   ```

   In this case the calling context is the brand new object you create

Now, **most importantly**, if the object `o` is the prototype of another object `o1`,  calling the above methods through `o1` yields the same results.

Here are the three cases. Notice the console.

```js
o = {
    f: function() {console.log(this)},
    g: 1
}

o.f();  

o.f.call({name: 'new context'})

obj = new o.f()


o1 = Object.create(o);
o1.f();
```